# When I run java jar file normally everything is okey, when run the same jar in task sheduler, there are some issues

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, scheduled-tasks

I written program in java which, open browser, do screenshtot and save this screenshot. To take a screenshot of the bigger part of the screen, I reduce the screen zoom to 75%. If i run my file normally (just click in runnable jar) everything is okey. But when i run my jar file in task sheduler, program dont respect zoom and do screenshot in normally size (100%). I checked many times, and did everything correctly.

This is part of my code, which find element on side, passes in that place, zoom to 75%, wait 3 seconds and do screenshot.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/grafana-app/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/dashboard-grid/div/div[2]/div/plugin-component/panel-plugin-singlestat/grafana-panel/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/div"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); //find element by xpath and move there 
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '0.75'"); // change zoom in browser to 75%
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            doScreenShot(); // function which do screenshot



\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

private static void doScreenShot()
    {
        // doing a screenshot
                    File src= ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

                    try {
                        // now copy the  screenshot to desired location using copyFile //method
                        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("C:/Users/pl-admin-gm3/Desktop/DailyReports/Urls Health/Screenshots/"+ serverNames[i] +" - " + j +".png"));
                        j++;
                        }

                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    }
    }
```

Comment: which browser? you may want try to change the zoom settings through browser properties rather than using java script executor.

Comment: not sure if it helps you but the IEDriver will take a full screenshot without zooming.

Comment: @Sureshmani Can you explain how to do it? When i go to chrome://settings/, selenium didn't find any elements..

Answer (score 0):

try using sendkeys,

```
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT)); // Set to 90%
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT)); // Set to 80%
```

or resize the window if the application automatically adjust,

```
driver.get().manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Comment: It has to be automatic

Comment: if your application automatically resizes after window adjustment, you can try this and get a screenshot,driver.get().manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

Comment: zoom change the size of all page and we can see more without scrolling, get().manage().window().setSize changing only size of display screen, so it is not help when we want see more things on single page